# What shoud I do for solving this problem ? Problem is about SNORT

Tags: windows, snort

[image: ERROR SCREEN]
Snort, daq and WinPcap are installed. The rule files are located at a convenient place. How can I solve this problem? A clue is the ERROR line: Missing/incorrect dynamic engine lib specifier.

Comment: This appears to be off-topic since it is not a question about security, but about getting a piece of (albeit security) software installed.

Comment: Please copy [edit] your question to instead of a print screen image rather include a description of the problem. Copy/paste relevant screen text to the question and encapsulate it with a preformatted text markup (the `{}` button in the editor). This way, it'll be easier for others also interested in finding solutions to this particular problem by using text search, and won't require opening the attached image in a new tab to read its contents easier on smaller screens of mobile devices. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have to edit the specified configuration file C:\Snort\etc\snort.conf starting on line 245 to add the correct paths to the .dll files.

I found a video that explains the fix to your problem starting at the 7:00 minute mark on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ic07nBoweg

This video shows how to set up and fix Snort, including the error you are experiencing.